# why using strips in the url database Mysql php cannot be read

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem calling the database in the URL with MYSQL,
where I call the url post

`/post/**how-to-noodle-with-egg**`

why does the database call an error with a strip at the URL?

if me display in page use

```
$_GET['title'];
```

why only get "how"? why not get  full url? so page post me not found data because only get "how" not full text with strip

My code :

```
$a = $_GET['title'];

"SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE title = '$a";
```

in my database 
title : how-to-noodle-with-egg ( use strip )

maybe someone here can help my problem

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: @MohitKumar, I want to display the post from url

Comment: '$a will be '$a'

Comment: @MohitKumar, Then, how?

Comment: what comes in $a variable?

Comment: @MohitKumar, comes $a get $title

Comment: $a contains title with respective id of posts?

Comment: @MohitKumar, only the posts I call are not all, before I use ID to call data. now I try to call data using the title.

Comment: You want this     http://localhost/index.php?a=how-to-noodle-with-egg

Comment: yes, that's the url I've used htaccess. before :localhost/test/post.php/$title=how-to-noodle-with-egg, after : localhost/test/post/how-to-noodle-with-egg.

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL query is missing trailing `'`:

```php
"SELECT * FROM post WHERE title = '$a";
```

Should be:

```php
"SELECT * FROM post WHERE title = '$a'";
```

I'd also strongly suggest to properly escape `$a` to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: oh, I forgot to add it to the question, I've tried it like that, illegible.

Comment: So then please post a complete code so we'd be able to help you. Otherwise, we have to make blind guesses.

Comment: @5lava op wants post title in url ,with respective id from databases?

Comment: Well, if the problem is why `how-to-noodle-with-egg` was stripped down to just `how` (i.e. `$_GET['title'] == 'how'`) then op should look into webserver configuration. Specifically, how URL is parsed and turned into `$_GET` parameters.

Comment: $ a = $ _GET ['title'];
("SELECT * FROM post WHERE title = '$a'");

Comment: @AingMacan Can you do `var_dump($_GET);` and post the result?

Comment: /post/how-to-noodle-with-egg

if me call use:
echo $_GET['title'];

why only get "how" not full text with strip

Comment: I will try first